# In what episode does Geordi La Forge swear while standing at a computer terminal?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, episode-identification

When I was in kindergarten, I got in trouble in class because the Lego airplane I was building fell apart, and I yelled out "Damn!". The thing is, I didn't know what I was saying - my parents hadn't yet taught me what the word meant, and were very careful to never swear in front of me.  I think I picked up the word from Geordi La Forge on TV. At the time, I idolized and tried to emulate him.

I vaguely recall a scene where something was going wrong with the Enterprise, and Geordi was standing at a computer terminal trying to fix it, maybe in Engineering? Things weren't going well, so he said the word.  What episode could this be?
I was in kindergarten in '91-'92, it could have been a rerun though.

Comment: "Damn" was used quite a lot in TNG. A total of 111 times: http://scriptsearch.dxdy.name/?page=results&query=(%7Bseries%7Ctng,%7D)%20and%20(%7Bline%7Cdamn,%7D)

LaForge himself said it 20 times: http://scriptsearch.dxdy.name/?page=results&query=(%7Bseries%7Ctng,%7D)%20and%20(%7Bspeaker%7CLaForge,%7D)%20and%20(%7Bline%7Cdamn,%7D)

Comment: Thanks for the script search link, I didn't know about that.  Twenty is a lot, and most of them seem to fit the description of Geordi standing at a terminal.  Damn, indeed.

Comment: I can [narrow it down to seven](http://scriptsearch.dxdy.name/?page=results&query=(%7Bseries%7Ctng,%7D)%20and%20(%7Bspeaker%7CLaForge,%7D)%20and%20(%7Broom%7CEngineering,%7D)%20and%20(%7Bline%7Cdamn,%7D)) if I only include scenes in Engineering.  I'm thinking he said the word on its own, so it's probably Contagion, Tin Man, Best of Both Worlds, Identity Crisis, or Nth Degree.

Comment: @KevinK - As I briefly said in my answer on Movies.SE before this same question was closed/deleted, in Contagion he said it in the turbolift, so probably not that one.

Comment: Can we get a year?

Comment: @ThePopMachine I was in kindergarten in '91-'92, could have been a rerun though.  Looking over the script dates that doesn't seem to help much, sorry...

Comment: @KevinK, This had to be season 5 or earlier then.

Answer (score 8):

From your description, I think you are remembering S3E6 of TNG, "Booby Trap". LaForge is working with a holographic simulation of Leah Brahms, one of the Enterprise's designers, to get the enterprise out of a trap. Quote from the transcript:

> LAFORGE: Damn. Right back where it all started. Whoa, this is incredible. Leah, did you design this?

Answer (score 6):

I hopped on Netflix this evening to review each of the seven candidates noted in the question comments.  The one that best matches the imagery from my memory is in [Best of Both Worlds, Part 1 (S3E26)](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/174.htm):

> [Engineering]
>
> LAFORGE: Shield modulation has failed. They've locked on.
>
> [Bridge]
>
> WORF: Shields are being drained. Ninety percent. Eighty.
>
> [Engineering]
>
> LAFORGE: Trying to recalibrate nutation. Damn.
>
> [Bridge]
>
> WORF: Shields have failed.
>   PICARD: Fire all weapons.

On film there is a bit of a pause between sentences, and he puts more emphasis into the word than the script suggests.

I didn't realize the word was used as frequently as it was in the series, so honestly it could have been any/all of the episodes that influenced me.  Thank you all for helping me track down this important piece of my childhood!

Answer (score 4):

If it made a mark on you, I'm guessing it was in "The Nth Degree", S4E19, airdate 4/1/91:

> BARCLAY: Unclear. The interface isn't fast enough. 
>   LARSON: Commander La Forge. Overload indications on Argus generator five, seven and fourteen.
>   LAFORGE: ***Damn!***
>   BARCLAY: I can't do anything from here. I have to find a better interface.
>   LAFORGE: La Forge to Bridge. We're looking at a cascade reactor failure on the Argus.

It was quite emphatic because everything is going wrong and the Argus Array is going to blow up, before Barclay++ saves the day.